# Aligning columns with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I need to place a long list of links in the footer of a website, and I'd like to lay them out in columns. This code here produces the look that I'm trying to achieve...

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    padding: 8px;
    text-align: center;
}
ul li ul {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: auto;
}
ul li ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li>Link One</li>
      <li>Link Two</li>
      <li>Link Three</li>
      <li>Link Four</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li>Link One</li>
      <li>Link Two</li>
      <li>Link Three</li>
      <li>Link Four</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li>Link Five</li>
      <li>Link Six</li>
      <li>Link Seven</li>
      <li>Link Eight</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li>Link Nine</li>
      <li>Link Ten</li>
      <li>Link Eleven</li>
      <li>Link Tweleve</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This works just fine, but I'd prefer to not use multiple lists. Is there any way that can work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
ul {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: space-around;
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul li {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Link One</li>
  <li>Link Two</li>
  <li>Link Three</li>
  <li>Link Four</li>
  <li>Link One</li>
  <li>Link Two</li>
  <li>Link Three</li>
  <li>Link Four</li>
  <li>Link Five</li>
  <li>Link Six</li>
  <li>Link Seven</li>
  <li>Link Eight</li>
  <li>Link Nine</li>
  <li>Link Ten</li>
  <li>Link Eleven</li>
  <li>Link Tweleve</li>
</ul>
```

### [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r9rd1g70/)

Comment: Inline-flex was the key! Thank you @Michael_B this is perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Lists are going to inherently have some margin and padding issues in your implementation, so a little extra CSS markup is going to help. You also need to specify the `flex-grow` on the `li`.

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  list-style-type:none;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
  flex-grow: 1;
  }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>  
  <li>2</li>  
  <li>3</li>  
  <li>4</li>
</ul>
```